# Filter crashes/ANRs on Android Developer Console by app version

Tags: google-play

Is there way to filter crashes/ANRs on Android Developer Console by app version? Right now not only they are incorrectly grouped by type, they are also mixed from all kind of app versions.

Comment: Unfortunately there seem to be no such feature. It's really a shame. It would make it a lot easier to for instance verify a bug fix on a new version.